# Odoo15 Security, I can see invisible fields or groups

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I have a question about the Odoo Security.

Ass you can see, there is no button in the picture below. Because the button is invisible depends on the attrs.

For example this code:

`attrs="{'invisible': [('purchase_approve_admin', '!=', 'neutral')]}"`

[image]

But i can change this state from source code.

Like this:

I can control odoo forms' attrs from here.

[image]

[image]

So the buttons is visible.

Final:

[image]

Question is, How can i prevent this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate group like "**group_approve_ceo**" and assign it to your field, button, or menu. Only assign this group to the CEO or user who should have access

```
<button name="compute_purchase_approve_ceo"   type="object" class="btn btn-primary" groups="model_name.group_approve_ceo"/>
```